# HttpServer handler, additional Header cousing empty response in Java

Tags: java, http, http-headers, httphandler

I'm using an example from the tutorial but I want to add special header but if I only do the page doesn't respond and I got the error `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. This is the code:

```
public class EchoHeaderHandler implements HttpHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
        Headers headers = httpExchange.getRequestHeaders();
        headers.add("Additional header", "3000");
        System.out.println(headers.size());
        Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> entries = headers.entrySet();
        String response = "";
        for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : entries)
            response += entry.toString() + "\n";
        httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate between request and response.
You are trying to add to the request header, which should not be possible ... Add to response header 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/spi/http/HttpExchange.html#addResponseHeader(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)